How to use Entity Framework 6 in Windows Forms-App(.Net Framework) with vb.net?
It's pretty hard to find any documentation about this. I know that vb.net is pretty old, but I need to use it in this case. I want to implement Entity Framework in an existing Windows Forms-App(.Net Framework) (vb.net). I can't really find good tutorials that deal with vb.net.
What I already tried is following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms) to create the entity Framework classes in C#. I thought I could just access them from vb code. Sadly the c# classes aren't appearing in my data source wizard. Visual Basic classes do appear there.
I am working on a pretty old .NET Framework (4.5.2), but I also tried it in a newer version and it didn't work.
Are there any vb.net experts out here that can give me some tips?

Did you add a Project Reference to your C# library? Right-click Project > Add > Project Reference

I haven't used EF6 + .NET Framework in years, but here are my notes from that time:

Create Class Library (.NET Framework) Project
Use NuGet to add Entity Framework 6.0 package
Add new EDMX
Add > New Item > ADO.NET Entity Data Model > EF Designer from data
Do not pluralize/singularize table names
To add tables: Right-click EDMX > Update Model from Database
Compile project
Add reference to this project from other projects that will use this entity model


Thank you, the ADON.NET hint helpes me a lot. Got it to work with database first and code first method!

Haha sorry I misspelled ADO.NET !
Glad I could help. Happy programming!

Using EDMX is strongly disadvised.
